# How Load View Files from bin Folder in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewengine, asp.net-mvc-views, bin-folder

i work on asp.net mvc project and i transfer some view files to other project and enable "copy always" for them (to copy in bin folder of main project).

i create a custom view engine :

```
public class CMSViewEngine : WebFormViewEngine
    {
        public CMSViewEngine()
        {
            MasterLocationFormats = new string[]
            {
            "~/bin/Views/{1}/{0}.master",
            "~/bin/Views/Shared/{0}.master"
            };

            ViewLocationFormats = new string[]
            {
            "~/bin/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/bin/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/bin/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/bin/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/bin/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
            "~/bin/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
            "~/bin/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",
            "~/bin/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx"
            };
        }
    }
```

then added to mvc ViewEngine in global.ascx

```
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CMSViewEngine());

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

but my problem is: for showing view i get under exception:

> The view at '~/bin/Views/Forms/Index.cshtml' must derive from
>   ViewPage, ViewPage, ViewUserControl, or
>   ViewUserControl.

i try add `web.config` to view folder and also try add `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` to view files but not worked.

my web.config file for bin view files is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="TestProj.ContactFormApp" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

how can resolve this problem to load view file?

**Resolved:**

I must extend `CMSViewEngine` class from `RazorViewEngine` class (instead of `WebFormViewEngine`) to work correctly.

Comment: Why are you using WebFormViewEngine with cshtml Razor files?

Comment: how say mvc that load bin/views files for show after controller return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `WebFormViewEngine`, if that is the case you should not registere razor view files in `WebFormViewEngine`, your `CMSViewEngine` class should only contain WebForm based view files extensions like:

```
public class CMSViewEngine : WebFormViewEngine
{
    public CMSViewEngine()
    {
        MasterLocationFormats = new string[]
        {
        "~/bin/Views/{1}/{0}.master",
        "~/bin/Views/Shared/{0}.master"
        };

        ViewLocationFormats = new string[]
        {
        "~/bin/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
        "~/bin/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
        "~/bin/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",
        "~/bin/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx"
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are doing it with .NET Core you can just put the path to the view in bin folder and pass your model through.

```
 return View(@"bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\Views\Test.cshtml", new ReportLibrary.Person());
```